# RPCGEN introduction using C - can not create client

Tags: c, rpc

I'm trying to create a sample RPC program to learn more about it. What it does is only acknowledging that I have a working RPC program at hand before I start to meddle with it further. Before mentioning my problem here is my code, its very straightforward:

```
/* myrpc.x file*/
program MESSAGEPROG {
   version EVALMESSAGEVERS {
     int EVALMESSAGE(string) = 1;
   } = 1;
} = 0x20000002;
```

The remote method is as follows:

```
/* Remote method on a .c file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myrpc.h" 

int * evalmessage_1_svc(char **msg, struct svc_req *req)

{
    static int result = 0;
    printf("Message is: %s,\n",*msg);
    return (&result);
}
```

Finally, the test file is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myrpc.h" 

main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    CLIENT * clnt;
    char * server;
    char * msg;

    server = argv[1];
    msg = argv[2];

    clnt = clnt_create(server, MESSAGEPROG, EVALMESSAGEVERS, "visible");
    if (clnt == (CLIENT *)NULL) { printf("Failure\n"); }

    int * answer;
    answer = evalmessage_1(&msg,clnt);

    clnt_destroy(clnt);
    exit(0);
```

}

My problem is, I get the output : "Failure", indicating that I couldn't create the client. I'm using ubuntu/linux as my platform and using C as my programming language. I'm not having problems when building the project.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the problematic line :

```
clnt = clnt_create(server, MESSAGEPROG, EVALMESSAGEVERS, "visible");
```

Changing the last parameter to "udp" worked for me.

```
clnt = clnt_create(server, MESSAGEPROG, EVALMESSAGEVERS, "udp");
```